# How to see Adwords Converstions report?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have the following code:

```
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-1234567879/D-vACLXiz4IBEID834AD',
        'value': "5000",
        'currency': 'ZAR',
        'transaction_id': '12345'
    });
  </script>
```

This code is executed when an order is placed on my website. And I can see the conversions working in Adwords:

[image]

But nowhere can I find a place in Adwords where I can actually see this transaction_id. Why would Adwords allow me to provide this info, if I can't get the transaction_id afterwards. All I want is a list of transaction IDs that were as a result of Adwords. But all the reports I find only show totals. None that can give me the individual ids.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

In fact, I can't even see the individual amounts. I must be missing something obvious because surely if I am able to provide the value and the transaction_id, adwords should show this data to me somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

From the research I've done, it looks like this is actually not possible to do through Adwords.

You should read through [this section of an article about gtags](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/#sending_dynamic_conversion_data) as it states:

> The transaction_id field lets you provide an optional identifier for the transaction. This ID is used by AdWords to de-dupe multiple conversion events that may be fired for with the same transaction_id and avoid counting the conversion multiple times. This sometimes happens when users can access a cached version of the conversion page, which may contain the event snippet embedded in it.

Answer (score 0):

The transaction ID is actually only on there for the ability to de-duplicate transactions.

You can read more at:  https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6386790

But the key section is found in the note area

> Note Order IDs won't be reported in AdWords.

If you want to traceback order IDs to AdWords campaigns you'll have a lot easier time integrating with Google Analytics where you can report on both transaction IDs and AdWords traffic together.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? How exactly do you do that?

Comment: To track transaction IDs in Google Analytics you need to setup eCommerce tracking.   Instructions found at:  https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009612?hl=en

Essentially, when a purchase is made you fire an event that passes back the transaction information to Google Analytics.  


If you don't already have auto-tagging turned on in your AdWords account turn that on, and be sure to link your AdWords account with your Google Analytics account.


You will then be able to see transaction IDs in Google Analytics, and tie these back to your campaigns, ads, keywords, and more.